# environment setup for ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

currently i am doing environment setup for react.js with npm (babel,  webpack and etc.) and i now i am filling webpack.config.js file and tutorial that i am following has next code :

```
 module: {
  rules: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
     }
  ]
},
```

and as i see in presents property there are written es2015 (ECMAScript 5) and i want to know it is better be like that or i should switch it to ES6  or ES7 because it is 2019 and even ES6 has way too more features. i just started react and if i asked something stupid, correct me. thanks

Comment: are you using create-react-app ?

Comment: no i am not using, i thought it would be more professionally correct if i setup environment this way

Comment: The best way to start react.js from scatch is to use the default function `create-react-app`. Then you don't worry about webpack configurations. it's also more stable right now than few years ago.

Comment: but it is my opinion to start from this point i don't like going into easy ready stuff and edit it, i consider this way, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `@babel/preset-env` package instead of es2015

Answer (score 2):

You are right, that tutorial is outdated, you should use [@babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) instead. It is a single drop-in replacement for all `esXXX` presets.

> **@babel/preset-env** is a smart preset that allows you to use the latest
>   JavaScript without needing to micromanage which syntax transforms (and
>   optionally, browser polyfills) are needed by your target
>   environment(s). This both makes your life easier and JavaScript
>   bundles smaller!

Comment: i got error just now, now i am also going to install @babel/core (i had babel-core) :D